# How get type or id data sent post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have this code for send date:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
    <input name="file[]" type="file" id="img">
    <textarea name="file[]" rows="5" cols="50" id="textarea"></textarea>
    <input name="file[]" type="text" id="text" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="upload" name="submit" id="upload" class="upload"/>
</form>
```

and this code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $textarea=$_POST['file'];
        $implodetextarea=implode(",",$textarea);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($textarea); i++){
            echo $textarea['id'][$i];//This is wrong 
        }
    }
?>
```

Now how to get the type of data and how you can distinguish between the image or text, or others?

Comment: files will be in the `$_FILES` superglobal everything else in `$_POST`

Answer (score 1):

Data validation in Windows is based on the honor system - a file's suffix (.txt, .jpg, .zip, etc.) tells the system what kind of data is in the file. Of course a suffix can be changed, so it's not a perfect system. In other operating systems file suffixes are less prevalent and data validation, when required, must be done by examining the contents of the file. For example, if you're expecting the user to upload a jpg, you can use PHP's fopen and fread to search the uploaded file for jpg headers. In short, you can't be sure what kind of file is being uploaded without cracking it open and reading the contents.

Comment: the mime type is determined by the browser for populating the $_FILES array

Answer (score -1):

You can look for the files mime type.